# Inconsistent data fetching result during Next.js deployment on DigitalOcean

Tags: javascript, next.js, digital-ocean

**Introduction**

I'm encountering an issue with my Next.js deployment on DigitalOcean. During the build phase I need to statically generate my pricing page. Locally everything works file, I can see the data gets fetched and builds the page correctly. However on DO I see that `getProducts` function returns no data.

**Debug**

Here's the `getStaticProps` function:

```
export const getStaticProps: GetStaticProps = async ({ locale }) => {
  const products = await getProducts(undefined, true, true)
  console.log('Debug whether products get fetched during build: ', products)
  if (products.data == null) {
    return { redirect: { permanent: true, destination: '/500' } }
  }
  return {
    props: {
      ...(await serverSideTranslations(locale ?? 'en', [
        'common',
        'pricing',
        'faq'
      ])),
      products: JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(products.data))
    }
  }
}
```

**Result locally:**

```
Debug whether products get fetched during build:  
{
   data: [{...}, {...}, {...}, {...}, {...}],
   meta: { current_page: 1, from: 1, last_page: 1, to: 5, total: 5 }
}
```

**On DigitalOcean:**

```
Debug whether products get fetched during build:  
{
   data: [],
   meta: { current_page: 1, from: 0, last_page: 1, to: 0, total: 0 }
}
```

Both deployments are connected to the same database. I'm unsure why the data fetched during the build process on DigitalOcean returns an empty array, while locally it returns the expected data.

I would appreciate any insights or suggestions on how to resolve this inconsistency.